# Как получить через регулярное выражения число и тире

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Подскажите как можно получить, проверить текст вида:

```
1-2 дня вытащить 1-2
4-5дня вытащить 4-5
1день вытащить 1
8дней вытащить 8
```

как правильно сделать проверку через регулярновое выражение и вытаскивать по этому принципу?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
preg_match_all('/([\d+-]+)\s*д(?:ень|ня|ней)/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[1]);
```

https://3v4l.org/2liJF

https://regex101.com/r/eA6EFY/1